# Is it possible for a Wizard to be immortal and still become a lich?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard, undead

Could a level 20 Wizard with the Immortality Arcane Discovery turn himself into a Lich?

Comment: Regardless of if you can or not.... what's the point once you are immortal? Isn't that the whole reason wizards become Liches in the first place, so they don't die?

Comment: In the title you asked about wanting, in the body about possibility. What is what you really want to know?

Comment: @Theik Unlike the [lich](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/lich/)'s supernatural ability rejuvenation, if a dude who possesses the arcane discovery [immortality](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-discoveries/arcane-discoveries-paizo/immortality/) dies he doesn't automatically come back. So there's no apparent reason to take the discovery immortality if you're already a lich, but there's totally a reason to become a lich even if you've already taken the discovery immortality.

Comment: Yeah Immortality in this context is not dying over time; you're still susceptible to being reduced to -Con damage and other methods of dying

Answer (score 2):

> “Lich” is an acquired template that can be added to any living creature (referred to hereafter as the base creature), provided it can create the required phylactery.

> #### The Lich’s Phylactery
>
> [...]
>
> Each lich must create its own phylactery by using the Craft Wondrous Item feat. The character must be able to cast spells and have a caster level of 11th or higher. The phylactery costs 120,000 gp to create and has a caster level equal to that of its creator at the time of creation.

<sup>([Lich template description](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lich/))</sup>

These are the only requirements for becoming a lich: be living, have Craft Wondrous Items, be able to cast spells with a caster level of 11th or higher, and spend 120,000 gp. None of these requirements says you have to be mortal, so the immortality arcane discovery causes no problems for a wizard who otherwise meets the requirements.